# Dynamic where in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, search

Hi I have this LINQ query:

```
var q =
    (from vr in Util.db.ValuationsRequests
     where vr.dtSubmitted != null
     select vr
     ).AsEnumerable<ValuationsRequest>();
```

But I want to do a search with 3 more parameters: paramValuationId (int), paramValue (boolean), paramTitle (string).

Something like:

```
if (paramTitle != string.empty)
//add this field to the where
```

But if the paramTitle is empty I do not want to search for it.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: What are the corresponding fields to compare your optional parameters to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string paramTitle = "hello";
var q =
    (from vr in Util.db.ValuationsRequests
     where vr.dtSubmitted != null 
       && ( paramTitle == "" || vr.paramTitle == paramTitle)
     select vr
     ).AsEnumerable<ValuationsRequest>();
```

Comment: Your AND clause makes my eyes hurt. `&& (paramTitle == "" || vt.paramTitle == paramTitle)` please!

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet.... lol, sorry about that...your right, should have simplified

Comment: Won't paramTitle == "" potentially cause any index on the field not to be used? Wouldn't it be better to build up the where dynamically in code then only execute the SQL that applies?

Comment: I have accepted your answer, and also gave you +1 for making it more clear. And by the way: you have "vt.paramTitle" it's "vr.paramTitle", I hope no one gets confused with that. :)

@fearofawhackplanet I also gave you a +1.

Comment: Awesome, I've been trying to figure out how to do this. Does @Dave have a valid concern?

Answer (score 2):

```
var q =
(from vr in Util.db.ValuationsRequests
 where vr.dtSubmitted != null
 select vr
 ).AsEnumerable<ValuationsRequest>();

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(paramTitle))
   q = q.Where(p => p.ParamTitle == paramTitle);
```